# Como converter array json em um objecto no angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho um app móvel, tenho um `array` a ser gerado através do php o que pretendo agora e no `angularjs` transformar o array em um objecto pois quando quero pegar por exemplo o id dá undefenid porque esta como `array` e tem de ser objecto gostaria de saber como posso transformar esse `array` que bem do php em um objecto ?

**PHP**

```
$result_posts_home = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts_home WHERE activo = :activo ORDER BY id DESC ");
$result_posts_home->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result_posts_home->execute();
$posts_home = $result_posts_home->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($posts_home as $row_posts_home) {

    $result_posts_home_anexos = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts_home_anexos WHERE id_mae = :id_mae AND seccao = :seccao ");
    $result_posts_home_anexos->bindParam(':id_mae', $row_posts_home->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_posts_home_anexos->bindValue(':seccao', 'thumbnail', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result_posts_home_anexos->execute();
    $row_posts_home_anexos = $result_posts_home_anexos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // VALIDA SE USER JA TEM LIKE NO POST

    $total_likes = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id_post = :id_post AND user_id = :user_id ");
    $total_likes->bindValue(':id_post', $row_posts_home->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $total_likes->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $total_likes->execute();
    $likes = $total_likes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    $noticias[] = array(
        'id'        => $row_posts_home->id,
        'id_anexo'  => $row_posts_home_anexos->id_anexo,
        'tipo'      => $row_posts_home_anexos->tipo,
        'likes'     => $row_posts_home->likes,
    );

}

echo json_encode($noticias);
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ListaNoticiasHome', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, sessionService, $partilharRecursos) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_noticias_home.php").success(function (data) {
        $scope.noticias_home = data;

        $partilharRecursos.set('idNoticia', data.id);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está retornando um Array. Portanto deveria fazer assim:

```
$http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_noticias_home.php").success(function (data) {
    $scope.noticias_home = data[0];

    $partilharRecursos.set('idNoticia', $scope.noticias_home.id);
});
```

Chamo atenção ao fato de retornar um array na sua API. 
É [inseguro](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines#Protect_against_JSON.2FJavaScript_Hijacking), portanto, remova-o do lado server e retorne o objeto diretamente

Note que não fiz nenhum tratamento de erro, ou para validar se existem dados no array. Faça-o de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Note também que estou partindo do princípio que você precisa apenas no primeiro elemento do array. Se este não for o caso, eu retornaria o json assim:

```
{"result": [{"id": 1,....}, {"id": 2,....}]}
```

Para formatar o resultado assim em php faça o seguinte:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->result = $noticias;
echo json_encode($obj);
```

No angularjs você deverá iterar esses elementos e aplicar sua regra conforme a necessidade:

```
$http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_noticias_home.php").success(function    (data) {
    $scope.noticias_home = data.result;
    $partilharRecursos.set('idNoticia', data.result[0].id);

    angular.forEach(data.result, function(value, key){
       console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });        
});
```

Comment: E no php como faria para retornar como fiz no segundo exemplo ? pode editar e por como ficaria a parte do php

Comment: Você está retornando múltiplos objetos, qual deles você irá definir como idNotícia?

Comment: Eu quero o id mas vai sempre undefened e eu tenho varias noticias nao pode ser buscar o primeiro tem de ir buscar automaticamente

Comment: Não entendi sua última frase

Comment: cooquei essa formatação no php mas agora manda-me o id de outra noticia quando clico numa outra noticia nao manda o id correcto da que estou a clicar

Comment: Detalhe melhor o que você precisa, não consigo ajudá-lo mais do que isso com os detalhes fornecidos.

Comment: Eu tenho uma zona onde listo varias noticias, nessas noticias tenho um botao para cada para fazer gosto o que esta acontecer agora e que esta a mandar o id da noticia mas nao o correcto da noticia que estou a clicar

Comment: Em qual objeto você armazena esses id's? no partilharRecursos? pois ele recebe apenas 1 id e você está retornando vários em sua API. Você deve saber qual deve armazenar. O problema do array foi resolvido, talvez seria caso para outra pergunta

Comment: sim estou a armazenar no partilharRecursos o que eu quero e que armazene ai o id da noticia que estou a clicar